# How can I give clients read-access to an array in Swift?

Tags: swift

A class contains a private array

```
private  var _members = [Member]()
```

*How can I give clients **read access** to that array?*

Clients should be able to access the members, but not modify the array.
The following solution is probably too expensive

```
var members : [Member] { return _members } // too expensive?
```

It is too expensive because, if I got it right, it returns the entire array each time the client access an element (`theObject.members[i]`)

My current solution is as follows:

```
var membersCount : Int { return _members.count }
func memberFrom(no:Int) -> Member { return _members[no] }
```

The client may thus iterate through the members as follows:

```
for i in 0..<theObject.membersCount {
     let member = theObject.memberFrom(no:i)
     ...
}
```

Question: Is there a better way to give clients read-access to an array?